# Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException when executing new job

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I've added a new function to an already working WebJob. It gets triggered correctly and picked up from the queue, but throws an exception when its run.

There are unit tests for the function and it works as intended.

The WebJob runs 7 other functions successfully.

Here's what I've done:

- Wrote the message that gets put on the queue
- Wrote the function to get called
- Added triggers to queue the message
- Registered the function in the WebJob to respond to the message(s)

**Fetching from queue**

```cs
public async Task CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync([QueueTrigger("%" + nameof(CheckPeripheralsWebJobMessage) + "%")] CheckPeripheralsWebJobMessage message)
{
    var cloudQueue = GetQueue(message.unitId);
    var idsToProcess = new List<int> { message.unitId };

    if (await cloudQueue.PeekMessageAsync() != null)
    {
        foreach (var messageInQueue in await cloudQueue.GetMessagesAsync(32))
        {
            try
            {
                // Try to remove message
                await cloudQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(messageInQueue);

                int id;
                var successfulParse = Int32.TryParse(messageInQueue.AsString, out id);

                if (successfulParse)
                {
                    idsToProcess.Add(id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // This has been deleted already by another job, so do not process this one
            }
        }
    }

    await RunJob(idsToProcess);  // This is the actual function
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
var config = new JobHostConfiguration
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    TypeLocator = new WebJobTypeLocator(
        ...
        ...
        ...
        typeof(CheckPeripheralsWebJob)      // %checkperipheralswebjobmessage%
    )
};
```

**Error message in console application**

```
Executed 'CheckPeripheralsWebJob.CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync' (Failed, Id=c5f2444f-0fda-4e94-aae7-e47d835ff3b4)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: CheckPeripheralsWebJob.CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode,HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode,T retVal,StorageCommandBase`1 cmd,Exception ex) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs : 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.<PeekMessagesImpl>b__45(RESTCommand`1 cmd,HttpWebResponse resp,Exception ex,OperationContext ctx) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs : 2700
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs : 299
   End of inner exception
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs : 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndPeekMessage(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs : 2165
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<CreateCallback>b__0(IAsyncResult ar) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs : 69
   at async ManagementPlatform.Services.UnitDiagnostics.CheckPeripheralsWebJob.CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync(CheckPeripheralsWebJobMessage message) at C:\Projekt\25_Server\Code\Services\UnitDiagnostics\CheckPeripheralsWebJob.cs : 53
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   End of inner exception
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is 'c5f2444f-0fda-4e94-aae7-e47d835ff3b4'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: CheckPeripheralsWebJob.CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode,HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode,T retVal,StorageCommandBase`1 cmd,Exception ex) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs : 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.<PeekMessagesImpl>b__45(RESTCommand`1 cmd,HttpWebResponse resp,Exception ex,OperationContext ctx) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs : 2700
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs : 299
   End of inner exception
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs : 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndPeekMessage(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs : 2165
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<CreateCallback>b__0(IAsyncResult ar) at c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs : 69
   at async ManagementPlatform.Services.UnitDiagnostics.CheckPeripheralsWebJob.CheckPeripheralsWebJobAsync(CheckPeripheralsWebJobMessage message) at C:\Projekt\25_Server\Code\Services\UnitDiagnostics\CheckPeripheralsWebJob.cs : 53
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   End of inner exception
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Which line is throwing the error? Something is throwing an HTTP 404 error. Possibly when you are peeking at the message.

Answer (score 0):

@davidg you were right, thank you.

`"Possibly when you are peeking at the message"`

The job was looking for a `message` object, but I was sending `message.unitId` to my lookup.